# Passing NODE_ENV from package.json to Docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I am trying to pass NODE_ENV=profiling-local from package.jso to Docker-compose and then run the script but it is not taking it and process.env.NODE_ENV= undefined is coming.

my docker-compose file:

```
    version: "2"
    services:
      logs_db:
        image: postgres
        ports:
          - "5434:5432"
        expose:
          - "5434"
        volumes:
          - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
          - ./db/setup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/seed.sql
        networks:
          - liven
        environment:
          POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust,
          NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV}
      event_engine:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        entrypoint:
          - 'sh'
          - '-c'
          - 'yarn install && yarn watch'
        volumes:
          - .:/src/app/
          - /src/app/node_modules/
        links:
          - logs_db
        depends_on: 
          - logs_db
        networks:
          - liven
    volumes:
      data:
        driver: local
      node_modules_volume:
```

my package.json

```
    {
      "name": "event-engine",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "event engine",
      "main": "src/index.js",
      "author": "DT Starts",
      "license": "MIT",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "watch": "nodemon -L --exec babel-node src/index.js --config nodemon.json",
        "start": "node ./dist/index.js",
        "build": "babel src -d dist",
        "dev": "docker-compose up",
        "profiling":"NODE_ENV=profiling-local docker-compose up"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.12.1",
        "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
        "@babel/node": "^7.12.1",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
        "@babel/register": "^7.12.1",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
        "eslint": "^6.8.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
        "eslint-plugin-babel": "^5.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
        "pino":"^6.11.2",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "pg": "^7.18.2",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "socketcluster-client": "^16.0.1",
        "uuid": "^8.3.1"
      }
    }
```

after but in my index.js file process.env.NOD_ENV is coming undefined.
I have tried almost every way to pass the enviromnet variable to docker-compose file from scrip of pacakge.json and from where my node.js code can take it but it is coming undefined.

Comment: Your `environment:` block is under the `logs_db:` container, not the `event_engine:` container, so your application won't see it.

Comment: still from package.json script it's showing undefind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify how you run this compose file, but I guess you didn't pass the build-arg:

```
docker-compose up --build-arg NODE_ENV=<value>
```